# How to split or duplicate an SHH connection terminal in Windows 11

Tags: ssh, windows-11

During an SSH connection with Win 11 terminal I would like to split my windows to get two ssh connections on the same server at a time.

I used the keyboard shortcut "Alt + Shift + D" to get my windows split, but it's not the SSH connection inside. I got a windows PowerShell terminal only. I know I have to type the `ssh username@hostname` to be connected on the server.

Is it possible to duplicate the ssh connection automatically ?

Putty tool is able to do that

Comment: Why can't you start up two SSH connections ?

Comment: What's stopping you from starting a second SSH connection?

Comment: In this case the ssh connection is present in a new tab. It's easier to split terminal windows than type username, hostname and password. Some times I like to watch in the split windows a `tail -f` result of the log file when I typed a  shell command

Comment: Wonder if you really want tmux.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the connection details (host/port/user) somewhere outside the terminal, which the OpenSSH client and Microsoft Terminal don't do automatically.

The terminal does support running a command in the new tab which you could use to launch another ssh session automatically by using a helper script, like:

```
// In settings.json
{ 
  "command": { 
    "action": "splitPane", 
    "split": "auto", 
    "profile": "profile1", 
    "commandline": "connect-to-server.script" 
  }, 
  "keys": "alt+shift+d" 
}
```

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions#split-a-pane

But there's no built-in support for duplicating SSH yet. There is an open request to add this kind of SSH connection features to windows terminal: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1280.

Check it out for some other examples of how to automatically start an SSH session using Profiles

---

The terminal does support [duplicating WSL paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/new-tab-same-directory#wsl) with some edits to your `.bash_profile`